# c# show up other character(letter) when key is press

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to make a code in C# (Global in windows)that when i press a key it show up other character(letter).
and i need help to white arabic letter if the expression sticks together how to make that

"but the most important thing for me how to make code that when some on pressed show up other letter"

if you can help me white arabic one  it will be amazing

Comment: Are you saying you want to write a keyboard _hook_, something that hooks into the keyboard driver and changes its behavior for the entire OS? Look up _Keyboard Hook_. You probably don't want to write one in C#. Why don't you just install Arabic as a UI language and an Arabic keyboard (the logical idea of a keyboard, not a piece of hardware)

Comment: You should edit your tags. There's nothing version-specific in your question and nothing that seems Facebook-y

Comment: @Flydog57 "Why don't you just install Arabic as a UI language" because my keyboard is English keyboard(all letter is English) and i thought to do this hooks so that when i press for example letter 'L' in keyboard it well show the letter L in Arabic ' ل '. and by the way can you help me to edit my tag i am new on stack overflow

Comment: You can tell Windows "treat me English keyboard as if it is Arabic". Then get some little stickers with Aleph, beh, the, etc characters and stick them on the front of the keys. https://www.lqmississauga.com/10-easy-steps-to-setup-arabic-keyboard-on-your-windows-computer.html

Comment: To edit your tags, click `Edit`, then click in the `Tags` field. Consider `C#`, `Windows` and `Keyboard` for tags